# How do I include a template file while allowing it to render its own dynamic content added via custom box?

Tags: custom-field, page-template

I have 3 theme files: `header.php`, `navigation.php` and `page.php`

`page.php` calls `header.php`
They both have content which is added to via a `custom box`.

`navigation.php` has some content added to it via a `custom box`.
Based on the page being called, I would want to include `navigation.php` within `header.php` as well.

How would I do this?

I want `navigation.php` to be included into `page.php` while both have content that is added to it via a `custom box`.

**My guess**
Create a page called 'Navigation', for example. I never display this link in my templates so that it's not used as a page on it's own even though it exists as one.
This will allow me to edit its contents.

Create another page by whatever name, this would use `page.php`.
`page.php` would use some function to include `navigation.php` based on `is_home()`.

If that idea is right, can someone please elaborate and give me details on what functions I would use, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include any template you want using `get_template_part()`

e.g.:

```
<?php get_template_part('navigation'); ?>
```

Using this function also gives you child/parent theme support.

Also of note, you could put:

```
<?php get_template_part('navigation','search'); ?>
```

Which would attempt to load `navigation-search.php`, but if that isn't found or doesn't exist, it will fallback and load `navigation.php` instead.

I use this in my personal code to make loading different excerpts for different post types easier, e.g.:

```
get_template_part('excerpt',$post->post_type);
```

It will load `excerpt.php` by default, but I could override it for any post type I wish e.g. `excerpt-page.php`

As a sidenote, use this function only for template files, do not use it as a general purpose include statement, e.g. it would be a bad idea to load a PHP library or a configuration file this way.